# ggplot2 Bar Graph remove unnecessary distance between axis label and 0 count on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a simple bar graph which x is the levels of a category variable 1 - 9, and z is the count of each level. But there is a distance at the bottom (marked in red), which I want to remove. I wasn't able to find helpful tips online. Could anyone help me with it? Thank you in advance!

```
ggplot(data = my_data,aes(x = factor(degree)), stat = "count") + geom_bar()
```

[image: Bar Graph]

Comment: @PoGibasJust wanted to post the same duplicate :)  But aosmith got a better one

Comment: @PoGibas Thanks for the duplicate. I knew it was out there somewhere, but I couldn't find it

Comment: Sorry I didn't use the right keyword. expand = c(0,0) works great! I also added limits = c(0,1700) to avoid cutoff. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `expand=` argument in the `scale_*` function controls the extra space around the edges of a plot.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars,aes(x = factor(cyl)), stat = "count") +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_y_discrete()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = mtcars,aes(x = factor(cyl)), stat = "count") +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Also see the new `expand_scale()` function, which is useful when you only want to remove the extra space at the bottom of the bars and not the top.